# Problems while extranting value

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I´m working with a table and I figure out that I have a field that is incorrect, what I´m trying to do is to get rid of the “.0”
To accomplish this, I tried the following code.

```
select id,
SUBSTR(cast(id as STRING), 1, LENGTH(cast(id as STRING))-1)
from `TABLE_1`
```

and the result i got is similar to this.

[image]

As you can see I´m loosing a digit

Then I change cast(id as STRING))-1 for cast(id as STRING))-2 and I got this error: “Third argument in SUBSTR() cannot be negative”

Any other way to get rid of ".0"´s? thank you.

Comment: The type of `id` field is `float` or `string` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `id` field has `NUMERIC` or `FLOAT64` type, you can directly `cast` your field as `INT64` and it will remove the digit after `.` :

```
# Input as NUMERIC
select CAST(CAST(3.0 AS NUMERIC) AS INT64) as id;

# Input as FLOAT64
select CAST(CAST(3.0 AS FLOAT64) AS INT64) as id;
```

The result is `3`